# Most efficient way to order by the average of a column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I know there's A way to do this, but I'm curious to know if there is a "best" way of doing this...

Let's say I have this table

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Troy | 2021-04-21 | 1 |
| Troy | 2021-04-20 | 2 |
| Troy | 2021-04-19 | 3 |
| Alec | 2021-04-21 | 3 |
| Alec | 2021-04-20 | 4 |
| Alec | 2021-04-19 | 5 |

I want to reorder the table based on the average of the "Value" column for each person.

Here is the expected output:

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alec | 2021-04-21 | 3 |
| Alec | 2021-04-20 | 4 |
| Alec | 2021-04-19 | 5 |
| Troy | 2021-04-21 | 1 |
| Troy | 2021-04-20 | 2 |
| Troy | 2021-04-19 | 3 |

Is there a most efficient way of executing this?

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Sure @Mureinik I added the expected output, but basically it's just the same table except "Alec" is ordered first because the average of his value column would be greater than Troys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the average value can be done either by aggregation in a query that groups by person and then it is joined to the table, or with `AVG()` window function which can be used directly in the `ORDER BY` clause and I believe is better for performance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY AVG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) DESC, Name, Date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0570d7ab7823ec475b4e2938f30f4c6e).

Comment: So like I said in my question, I'm aware that there is a way of doing this, but I guess I'm looking for a little bit more of an explanation as to why this is the MOST efficient way of doing this because my dataset is very large. Or if this is just the accepted way of performing this operation, you can also just say so, but I'm looking for something a little more than just "this is how you do it"

Comment: Also, the last "order by" should be `Date DESC` not `Value`

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather you do not specify in the question that you want the rows ordered by Date and and not value, so I would have to guess.

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather see a brief explanation in my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah that's totally fine I know I didn't specify it. I'm gunna accept this as the answer because those are the two ways I thought of doing it as well, but "I believe its better for performance" still doesn't really help me understand why lol. But after thinking more about it, I can't imagine that the other way would be faster somehow...